# react-native Navigator and non-stacked navigation (like tree)

Tags: navigation, react-native, navigator

I would like to implement a slack-like application that allow user to be in many Discussions and switch from one to another. A new Discussion view can be added at any moment.

I've read a lot on Navigator and react-native navigation in general. It's really simple to implement a stacked navigation like that:

```
Home
  Step 1
    Step 2
     Step 3...
```

But for more hierarchical navigation like:

```
Home
  Discussion 1
  Discussion 2
    Profile page
    Settings page
  Discussion 3
  ...
```

... where you can have few `Discussion` views opened. The ability to switch from one to other. And to add another Discussion view at any moment without un-mounting other views.

But if I understand well the documentation (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html) the only ways we have to add new route (=create new view) is `.push()` and `.replace()`.

- `.push()` destroy all the view "after" the current one and add the
  new view
- `.replace()` destroy the current view and add the view at
  the same position

So my route stack is:

```
Home > Discussion 1 (focused) > Discussion 2
```

And if I want to add a new `Discussion 3` view with .push() my new stack is:

```
Home > Discussion 1 > Discussion 3 (focused)
```

`Discussion 2` was destroyed.

I've read pieces of discussions around "nested Navigator to implement a tree-like navigation" but even if I put a Navigator around the Home view and if each scene has its proper Navigator (that reference the main one with `navigator` prop). The same problem remain for the root Navigator.

How to add a new view in a Navigator route stack, when my focused view is NOT **the last one** without crushing all the views after?

Answer (score 0):

As workaround and until a better solution, I've extended Navigator and added a new .pushToBottom() method:

```
pushToBottom (route) {
  var activeStack = this.state.routeStack;
  var activeAnimationConfigStack = this.state.sceneConfigStack;
  var nextStack = activeStack.concat([route]);
  var destIndex = nextStack.length - 1;
  var nextAnimationConfigStack = activeAnimationConfigStack.concat([
    this.props.configureScene(route),
  ]);
  this._emitWillFocus(nextStack[destIndex]);
  this.setState({
    routeStack: nextStack,
    sceneConfigStack: nextAnimationConfigStack,
  }, () => {
    this._enableScene(destIndex);
    this._transitionTo(destIndex);
  });
}
```

See: react-native/Libraries/CustomComponents/Navigator/Navigator.js:891

It solves the problem of jupimg from Discussion1 to a new Discussion4 without unmounting Discussion2 and Discussion3.

To solve the opening profile/settings/... pages from a Discussion view i've juste wrapped every discussion in a  component where  is the initialRoute and  are simply pushed/poped.